# Loopin a comprehension of list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
lst = [[['X', 'A'], 1, 2, 3], [['Y', 'B'],  1, 2, 3], [['Z', 'C'],  1, 2, 3]]
```

And i want to turn it into:

```
new_lst = [['X', 1, 2, 3], ['A', 1, 2, 3] ['Y', 1, 2, 3], ['B',  1, 2, 3], ['Z', 1, 2, 3], ['C',  1, 2, 3]]
```

I've got it to work with a a single one of them with comprehension.

```
 lst2 = [['X', 'Y'], 1, 2, 3]
fst, *rest = lst2
new_lst3= [[i, *rest] for i in fst]
```

Which gives me  `new_list3 = [['X', 1, 2, 3], ['Y', 1, 2, 3]]`

But I don't know how to loop to make it work on the full list.

Any good solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack each sublist into the list of letters and the "rest", then iterate over the letters to build new sublists from a letter and the rest.

```
new_lst = [[c, *rest] for letters, *rest in lst for c in letters]
```

Comment: Thas wored like a charm, very clean as well! Thanks

Comment: Another way might be to add the 2 parts as lists, but this is more elegant. `[[k]+j for (i, *j) in lst for k in i]`

Comment: `[c, *rest]` builds a single list object; `[k] + j` has to build two: `[k]` and the result of `[k].__add__(j)`.

Comment: Quick question: if i have for example ```` lst = [[['X', 'A'], [1, 2, 3], [['Y', 'B'],  [1, 2, 3], [['Z', 'C'],  [1, 2, 3]] ```` like this, would it still work?

Comment: So the numbers are in their own sublist rather than being "siblings" of the letter sublist? You would just need to drop the `*` in the unpacking: `[[c, *rest] for c, rest i lst for c in letters]`

Answer (score 2):

You're only missing the loop to iterate through the `lst`

```py
from pprint import pprint


lst = [[['X', 'A'], 1, 2, 3], [['Y', 'B'],  4, 5, 6], [['Z', 'C'],  7, 8, 9]]

new_lst = []
for elem in lst:
    fst, *rest = elem
    new_lst.extend([[i, *rest] for i in fst])

pprint(new_lst, indent=4)
```

**output**

```py
[   ['X', 1, 2, 3],
    ['A', 1, 2, 3],
    ['Y', 4, 5, 6],
    ['B', 4, 5, 6],
    ['Z', 7, 8, 9],
    ['C', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used pprint before. What does that do?

Comment: ah its pretty printer. It's nicer to print out dicts and lists with.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your list comprehension for a single element into a *nested* list comprehension for the entire list:

```
>>> lst = [[['X', 'A'], 1, 2, 3], [['Y', 'B'],  1, 2, 3], [['Z', 'C'],  1, 2, 3]]
>>> [[i, *rest] for (fst, *rest) in lst for i in fst]
[['X', 1, 2, 3], ['A', 1, 2, 3], ['Y', 1, 2, 3], ['B', 1, 2, 3], ['Z', 1, 2, 3], ['C', 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just replace the first term right with the first letter right?

```
lst = [[['X', 'A'], 1, 2, 3], [['Y', 'B'],  1, 2, 3], [['Z', 'C'],  1, 2, 3]]

for item in lst:
  item[0] = item[0][0];

print(lst)
```

Comment: No that doesnt work. The out is [['X', 1, 2, 3], ['Y', 1, 2, 3], ['Z', 1, 2, 3]]